# Kernel affine space of an L-function

Tags: number-theory, l-functions

Throughout this question, an L-function is both an automorphic L-function and an element of the Selberg class such that whenever $F$ and $G$ are L-functions, then so are $F.G$ and $F\otimes G$, where $\otimes$ denotes the Rankin-Selberg convolution.

Let's now consider the 'kernel affine space' of an L-function $F$, defined as the affine space of minimal dimension containing all the non trivial zeroes of $F$. The analogue of RH for $F$ holds if and only if its kernel affine space is 1-dimensional.

My question is the following: as the tensor product of $R^{n}$ with $R^{m}$ is isomorphic to $R^{mn}$ can one establish that the kernel affine space of $F\otimes G$ is 1-dimensional if and only if the kernel affine spaces of both $F$ and $G$ are themselves 1-dimensional? Is a 'motivic' interpretation possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The MO post was [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/247630/the-kernel-affine-space-of-an-l-function), but is deleted now.

Comment: Yes, cause from what I understand, one is not supposed to ask the same question on both sites.

Comment: Then the disclaimer is perhaps no longer necessary. I missed the question on MO, so I would be interested.